# Изменить nan на None

Tags: python

Как заменить **nan** на **None** в списке `q = [1,nan,nan]`?

```
q = [None if i == nan else i for i in q]
```

Так не работает и `nan = None` тоже не выходит.

Comment: ну так я пример показал, проверяйте с помощью `math.isnan()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для чисел выражение `i == i` ложно в том случае когда `i` имеет значение `nan`. Во всех остальных случаях оно истинно.

[https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN#Свойства](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN#%D0%A1%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0):

> NaN не равен ни одному другому значению (даже самому себе). Благодаря
> этому один из распространённых, однако не очевидных, способов проверки
> результата на NaN — это сравнение полученной величины с самой собой.

```
q = [i if i == i else None for i in q]
```

Если вы хотите чтобы ваш код легко читался, то лучше писать более явно:

```
import math

q = [i if math.isnan(i) else None for i in q]
```